# How to also include my app's name while sharing content?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

user can share a link from inside my app:

```
ShareLinkTask linkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
linkTask.Title = "I like it";
linkTask.Message = "I love this movie";
linkTask.LinkUri = new Uri(link, UriKind.Absolute);

linkTask.Show();
```

problem: I want to include my app's name too something like this `sent by my awesome app!`. If I append this to `Message` user can remove it. How can I add my app name without user be able to remove it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the built in share tasks, probably to protect the user from an app posting text without permission. To get this functionality you will have to implement it by working directly with the [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/), [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/), etc. APIs.

Comment: This is correct. Always give the user the choice to modify the content that is being shared - I, for one, would remove any app that tried to force me to share a link/name without my consent.